# Getting Breeze OData results in Container and Next0 object in .Net 5 web api

Tags: .net, .net-core, odata, breeze

I was trying .net5 with breeze from this git repo https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-demo/tree/master/server/NorthwindNet5. Its works as expected and I am getting result as below [image]

But when I add OData to breeze configuration and apply filter with select (http://localhost:4000/api/breeze/customers?select=Name) I am getting result in nested container.
[image]

This is because of AddNewtonsoftJson in ConfigureServices

```
 services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
        {
            //Set Breeze defaults for entity serialization
            var ss = JsonSerializationFns.UpdateWithDefaults(opt.SerializerSettings);
            if (ss.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver resolver)
            {
                resolver.NamingStrategy = null;  // remove json camelCasing; names are converted on the client.
            }
            ss.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; // format JSON for debugging
        });
```

Can anyone please suggest if there is any configuration changes need to made to get direct result after applying filters

Comment: OData is not  necessary to use Breeze with .NET 5.  Why did you add OData?

Comment: I need to add further filters and other operations like select which is provided by OData

Comment: Remove OData.  You need only the [BreezeQueryFilter] attribute on your controller in order to filter, select, expand, etc.

Comment: Thanks Steve, Yes it works with BreezeQueryFilter, but I am porting old .net framework project which already uses both Breeze and OData to .net 6. I cannot remove OData dependency while porting as it might be very hectic task, so that's the reason was looking to make sure existing changes work as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is fixed by adding package ODataNewtwonsoftJson, after adding this in configurationservices I am not getting additional OData information in response

Modified below code in startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.NewtonsoftJson;

services.AddControllers().AddODataNewtonsoftJson().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
        {

           // Set Breeze defaults for entity serialization
            var ss = JsonSerializationFns.UpdateWithDefaults(opt.SerializerSettings);
            if (ss.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver resolver)
            {
                resolver.NamingStrategy = null;  // remove json camelCasing; names are converted on the client.
            }
            ss.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; // format JSON for debugging

            //var ss = opt.SerializerSettings;
            //ss.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        });
```